Arguments against "The good life is a happy one"?
In a previous question I have referred to eudaimonia and mentioned that, I guess at least in hellenistic tradition the good life is a happy one.
However, now I wonder whether there is a counter to this?
My main concern is based on what we define the good life, and then how this would be different from the happy life. Any recommnedations for literature or philosophers to get into?

What do you mean by 'good'? Pleasant? Morally good? Tasty and/or nutritious? (Eat the happy apples, they're good, and good for you!)

I refer to it as the morally good.

Nietzsche is known for arguing the pursuit of happiness is a waste. https://bigthink.com/thinking/man-doesnt-want-happiness-says-nietzsche/ . Imagine you could press a button and cause horrible things to happen - death of your family, destruction of your intellect - and in compensation you are kept alive and become artificially happy and ignorant for a century. Would you want to press that button? I wouldn't.

Maybe I dont understand what eudiamonia really means. Happiness in the sense that I use it is something which is about a life going well for someone. Therefore, yes I guess on this basis a good life would be also a happy life given that the life has to go well in order for it to be considered good.

A utilitarian like Peter Singer would argue that the morally good life is one that maximizes happiness for the greatest number of people, which likely involves being vegetarian or vegan, and donating most of one's wealth to others. Intuitively, it seems like Singer's moral life is less happy than a selfish or hedonistic one.
But eudaimonia isn't exactly happiness, right? My vague memory is that eudaimonia is something like "that which we should pursue as humans" or "having lived life well", and that Plato spends a lot of time writing about how happiness or wealth is insufficient for eudaimonia.
So we can potentially try to unite eudaimonia and Singer by arguing "Living without the guilt of causing animal suffering and with the knowledge that you are doing the most good you can is essential to eudaimonia." in the same way Plato argues justice is essential.
But that seems odd and leads to some unpleasant conclusions. If the greatest pleasure all humans seek is living a utilitarian life, then Singer-inspired effective altruism should be focused on teaching people across the globe utilitarianism, instead of providing medicine or resources. And the argument there is pretty bizarre. "The good life is one spent advocating for eudamonia-utilitarianism (EU), because a life cannot be truly well-lived without EU, and so you should maximize the number of people who believe in EU." It becomes almost like a virus or a chain letter, and loses sight entirely of the "improving people's lives" portion of utilitarianism!
So in practice, I think Singer-style utilitarianism bites the bullet and claims that the moral life is less happy (potentially far less happy) than an immoral life. Obviously, one should still be happy to the degree one can, but not at the expense of contributing to broader global well-being.

@andrós Yeah, that's a fair criticism. I do think there's something fundamentally different about Singer's utilitarianism ("You should convince somebody of utilitarianism if you can, because then they'll also spend their money and time serving the greatest good") and this ("You should convince someone of EU because that will make them personally feel good, and secondarily, you should care about global health and stuff")
